# Recycling the TextView for text messaging

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to use the MultiAutoCompleteTextView (I'm assuming that's what it is) that's used for texting with my application or do I have to create my own?

Comment: What you mean? Can you elaborate? As per `MultiAutoCompleteTextView ` yes you can use it.

Comment: @havexz When you text with an android phone, it has suggestions come up as you type. I want the same TextView to be used in my application (same Tokenzier, same Adapter).

Comment: suggestions when you type in the To field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just talking about content area in the Messaging app. Then you dont have to use `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`, a simple `EditText` will do your job.

The suggestions you are talking about come not from auto complete but from IME (Input Method). For this you dont have to do anything, just use `EditText` for editing your text.

I hope this wat you looking. If not pls comment below.